# How to run this tictactoe Java Socket program?

Tags: java, sockets

I found the Tic Tac Toe example from this site (http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/javanetexamples/) quite interesting and wanna try it in Eclipse. I'm new to Java, any idea on how to run this program? Thank you!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is first run the server, then run the client two times (because you'll need an opponent to play the game). Two clients play the game.